# HTML5Boilerplate Build Script - How to pass dir.source variable on the command line

Tags: ant, build, html5boilerplate

We're using the HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script on Windows and I wondered if it's possible to specify the **dir.source** parameter on the command line when running **ant build**, rather than editing it in the **default.properties** file each time we want to build a template in a different directory.

> dir.source          = ./template/company1

The **dir.source** parameter changes constantly as were building templates within different directories for our CMS, such as **./template/company1** and **./template/company2** etc

If we can avoid editing the default.properties file every time we want to build a template in a different directory that would be great, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
<javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${build.dir}"/>
```

and call it with:

```
ant -Dsrcdir="template/company1"
```

is it what you need?